# Manipulation of time field in InfluxDB

Tags: timestamp, format, influxdb

I have a time column in my database in the following format:

```
time                IMEI
----                ----
1555355829000000000 35269308:173212:16
1555355856000000000 35838706:010988:33
1555355865000000000 35578909:300271:07
1555355866000000000 35184109:712918:08
1555355868000000000 35775408:159140:45
```

I have to query new entries in the last 15 minutes using time in the given format. What is the format of this timestamp and how query new rows that were added in the last 15 minutes?

Comment: Please format your example better, it's not clear to me if these numbers are multiple fields or just one

Answer (score 0):

you can add `where > time() -15m`
the Unix timestamp is in nanoseconds so 1555355868000000000 is Monday 15 April 2019 19:17:48 GMT